# How do I disable the clipboard sharing feature in Synergy? 

Tags: synergy

I don't want to share my clipboard between 3 computers I'm sharing with synergy.  How do I disable that?

Comment: Man, I wish I could ENable clipboard sharing in Synergy...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an issue in their issue tracker over here: http://synergy-foss.org/tracker/issues/802

The title of the issue is "Option to disable all clipboard sharing" so I think that's what you're looking for.

Unfortunately the issue is 6 years old and just three months ago the version target was deletet. Even though the issue is "accepted" its priority is still "low" so apart from the fact that **this feature is not yet available** it might take a little longer until it finally will be.